# Creating random URLs in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, forms, url

I'm creating a project where:

1. A user submits an input into a form
2. That data is input into the database
3. A random URL is generated (think imgur / youtube style links)
4. The user is redirected to that random URL
5. The input data is display on that random URL

forms.py

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    user_input = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label="")
    random_url = forms.CharField(initial=uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper())
```

models.py

```
class AddToDatabase(models.Model):
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    random_url = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def Home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_input = request.POST.get('user_input', '')
            random_url = request.POST.get('random_url', '')
            data = AddToDatabase(user_input=user_input, random_url=random_url)
            data.save()

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})

    else:

        form = InputForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{form}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm new to Python / Django, which is probably obvious. The above code allows users to submit an input which is succesfully added to the database. It also generates 6 random characters and adds that to the database.

The problem is I don't know how to turn that random code into a URL and redirect the user there after submitting the form.

I've tried a couple of methods so far, such as adding `action="{{ random_url }}"` to the `index.html` form, as well as adding `url(r'(?P<random_url>\d+)', views.Home, name='home')` to `urls.py`

Comment: Note that a "6 character UUID" isn't a thing. What you're doing is generating a UUID, then taking the first 6 characters from it. That's much more likely to generate a collision than a proper UUID is.

Comment: Understood and edited, thanks!

Comment: If you're taking the UUID, remember that it comes back with the `-` character. You'd (probably) want to replace that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
import uuid

class AddToDatabase(models.Model):
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    random_url = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import AddToDatabase
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = AddToDatabase
      fields = ["user_input"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def Home(request):
    form = InputForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            form_instance.save()
            return redirect("form_detail", random_url=form_instance.random_url)
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})


def form_detail(request, random_url):
    template = "form_detail.html"
    context = {}
    form_detail = get_object_or_404(AddToDatabase, random_url=random_url)
    context["form_detail"] = form_detail
    return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^home/$' views.Home, name="home"),
url(r'^form-detail/(?P<random_url>[-\w]+)/$', views.form_detail, name="form_detail")
]
```

in form_detail.html template

```
<div>
  <p> User Input : {{ form_detail.user_input }}</P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using something like [Hashids](http://hashids.org/python/) for your URLs instead of `uuid.uuid4()[:6]`, but I think your immediate problem is in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'(?P<random_url>\d+)', views.Home, name='home')
```

Here your regular expression for `random_url` is `\d+`. [`\d+` matches one or more decimal digits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), but the values generated by `uuid.uuid()[:6]` aren't decimal. I think `\w` will be a better fit.

The other problem is that `views.Home` doesn't accept the "random URL", so it never knows which one to display. Give it a second argument:

```
def Home(request, random_url=None):
```

and then use `random_url` inside `Home` to load the correct page from the database. I suspect this should actually happen in a new view function, but I'm not clear on what each page represents so I can't recommend a good name for it.

Comment: The problem is that the `def Home` is used to display the homepage (index.html - mydomain.com) and the form, so I can't change the `urls.py` for that. If I create another Django app then I'm not sure what I add to the html forms `action="..."` to get it working

Comment: Again, I'm not sure that using the same view for both of these cases makes sense, but you can make the `random_url` argument optional as I've shown in my updated answer. (Side note: You may want to rename `random_url` to something like `slug`, which is a fairly common term for this kind of thing. In my opinion, "random" doesn't really apply here.)

Comment: Changed, thank you! Do you know if I need to add something to `action` in `<form action=" " method="POST">`?

Comment: @Liam, since you are posting back to the same URL you shouldn't need to set an `action`. I guess you're still having problems? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's sorted now, I appreciate your help!